# Elementary number theory problem involving binomial theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

**Exercise**. Let $a,b$ be real numbers, such that $a+b$ and $ab$ are integers. Show that $\forall n\in \Bbb N$: $(a^n+b^n)\in \Bbb Z$.

I tried to use the binomial formula: $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{{n}\choose{k}}a^{n-k}b^k$, saying that since $a+b$ is an integer, then $(a+b)^n$ is also an integer. But I could not say anything about members of the sum because of the different powers of $a$ and $b$. After that, I tried to determine the values of $a$, and $b$, failing.
Finally, I found a way to show that $a^{2^n}+b^{2^n}$ is an integer, which is better than nothing but is not a solution to the exercise.

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed by *strong* induction by noting that $a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}=(a^n+b^n)(a+b)-ab(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$ and that $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

$(a^n + b^n)(a+b) = a^{n+1} + a^{n}b + b^{n}a + b^{n+1} = a^{n+1} + b^{n+1} + ab(a^{n-1}) + ab(b^{n-1})$

So:
$a^{n+1} + b^{n+1} = (a^n + b^n)(a+b) - ab(a^{n-1} + b^{n-1})$

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).